# Pulsar Multiple client in one application

Tags: apache-pulsar

When using apache pulsar in k8s, is it possible to create multiple pulsar clients in one application and connect to pulsar at the same time? I'm aware that the convention is to use a single pulsar client but i'm curious if multiple clients are possible. Would this not cause any errors?

Comment: do you mean to use one multiple clients within an container with in a pod? or do you meean tho have multiple containers (like a replicaset) connecting to the same topic?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on client library, most of them allow it, but some of them don't. Having one client is not just a convention, but a performance rule - many things are cached on client layer, so you generally should avoid create multiple clients.